# Why does mcrypt encryption includes a lot of null chars in the final string?

Tags: php, encryption

My question is why simply `decrypting` the `encrypted string` using PHP's mcrypt functions causes to have a lot of `null (\0)` chars the final result? and how to get the actual first string with the exact same length?

#### Example code to test

```
// Mcrypt Encrypt
function en_mcrypt($string)
{
    return bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, 'Y6r6gYNR5xG6Ou55q2Vf83G31t4KG24j', $string, 'ecb'));
}


// Mcrypt Decrypt
function de_mcrypt($string)
{
    return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, 'Y6r6gYNR5xG6Ou55q2Vf83G31t4KG24j', hex2bin($string), 'ecb');
}

$string    = 'test-1234';
$encrypted = en_mcrypt($string);
$decrypted = de_mcrypt($encrypted);

echo "{$string} (".strlen($string).")<br>";
echo "{$encrypted} (".strlen($encrypted).")<br>";
echo "{$decrypted} (".strlen($decrypted).")<br>";
```

#### PHP Output:

```
test-1234 (9)
e9fc266f9a2f275ca3f4435c53c662a1 (32)
test-1234 (16)
```

> P.S. I'm aware of EBC encryption security concerns, so lets skip that part here.

Comment: It is best not to use `mcrypt`, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. `mcrypt` has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: @zaph Actually no user data is involved here. also it's a single string encryption in the entire project, AFAIK CBC is good to avoid detection of same strings encrypted with same password. also this string is not very important.

Comment: Ah, ECB encryption security concerns, sure, why be concerned, it is only the user's data at risk. Along the same line of reasoning Blowfish should not be used in new work if security is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block ciphers require the input to be an exact multiple of the block size, 8-bytes for Blowfish. If padding is not supplied it is likely that bytes following the data to be encrypted will be used as pad and they may well be 0's.

"test-1234" is 9-bytes so somehow 7-bytes of padding must be added.

The usual solution is to specify a padding option to the encryption and decryption functions and they will silently add/remove the padding. Note that mcrypt only supports non-standard 0 padding, adding confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much for great explanation, so I have to either make sure the `padding is added before encryption and removed after decription` or use the `trim()` function after decryption. I just didn't understand why this is happening randomly and now I do.